# Bluez + BlueAlsa: AVRCP commands not received

Tags: alsa, bluetooth, bluez

I cannot see any AVRCP communication when using dbus-monitor. Not a single signal nor property changed.

I use `Bluez 5.68` and `BlueAlsa v4.1.0-7-ge6218b5`

Logs on BT speaker connection:

```
Aug 02 10:18:03 nuc058 kernel: input: Grundig JAM (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input21
Aug 02 10:18:03 nuc058 systemd-logind[557]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (Grundig JAM (AVRCP))
```

I can see those commands incomming with `hci-dump`.

I confirmed that I can sends those commands to my phone. I just cannot receive anything from speakers and headphones on DBus layer.

Where should I start checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluez creates `/dev/input/event*` char. device file (here, it is `/dev/input/event4`). Using cat on this file will give you a binary output with incomming AVRCP/AVCTP commands. For human readable stuff use

```
 $ sudo evtest /dev/input/event*
```

or parse it with `<linux/input.h>` utils.

If you would like to have dbus signal emitter - you have to write your own.